# Generating Python Documentation with doxygen produces broken links to functions

Tags: python, automation, documentation, doxygen

Doxygen version: 1.8.12  --Default Configuration

I have been generating my Python doc using Doxygen. It have worked well while on documenting classes. I have built now, however, a couple of modules with some functions which I am documenting as follows:

```
 ## @file
 #  my module comment

 ##
 # my function
 # @return 0
 def func():
     return 0
```

It then creates a tab `Files` where I can find my module files. However when I click them, a list of functions is shown as links, that are broken (when clicked upon the page is redirected to itself), and the actual definitions of the module are appended at the end of the page.

What should I do to avoid having broken links, maybe a similar behavior as what happens with the classes (where functions have their separated html) is more desirable

====UPDATE====
While inspecting the generated html code, apparently the links are pointing towards an address in this style:

```
Documtenation/myfilepy.html#some_hash
```

Whereas the actual page sections have ids on this style:

```
 file_some_hash
```

the correct way to call the links should be:

```
Documentation/myfilepy#file_some_hash
```

How can I make for doxygen to either drop the `file_` or to correctly generate the links?

Comment: Please specify doxygen version. Please create a MWE so we can try to reproduce the problem. When the \file command is used in the same file as it describes please don't use the <fiulename> argument n otherwise see to it that it has the right extension.

Comment: I have added the version now. The minimal working example is given by the code as I use the default configuration of doxygen

Comment: @albert could you clarify a bit what you mean with don't use the filename argument so I can correct it? thx

Comment: Just use `@file` instead of `\file <filename>` when you have the comment with `\file` in `<filename>`.

Comment: sure, I can do that.. but again that does not solve the problem right :P

Comment: Correct doesn't solve the problem, I have no workaround either at the moment I'll write up an answer).

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with 1.8.12 (and also with 1.8.14 the current and preferred version as well as with the current development version). I see on the `Files` page a link to `myfile.py` (as I removed the word `myfile` from the `\file` command). On the `myfile.py` page I see 1 link to `myfile.func` but the reference goes nowhere.

When attempting the same with a C function it does work.
Looking into the HTML code I see (for C), in the `Functions` part:

```
<a class="el" href="bb_8c.html#a916cba588658b3be41b91489a560a664">c_func</a>
```

and

```
<a href="#a916cba588658b3be41b91489a560a664">More...</a>
```

and further down in the `Function Documentation` part:

```
<a id="a916cba588658b3be41b91489a560a664"></a>
<h2 class="memtitle"><span class="permalink"><a href="#a916cba588658b3be41b91489a560a664">&#9670;&nbsp;</a></span>c_func()</h2>
```

Looking into the HTML code I see (for Python), in the `Functions` part:

```
<a class="el" href="myfile_8py.html#a3f1962c8fd3ce4b252b1015bf4cb3c32">myfile.func</a>
```

and

```
<a href="myfile_8py.html#a3f1962c8fd3ce4b252b1015bf4cb3c32">More...</a>
```

and further down in the `Function Documentation` part:

```
<a id="file_a3f1962c8fd3ce4b252b1015bf4cb3c32"></a>
<h2 class="memtitle"><span class="permalink"><a href="#file_a3f1962c8fd3ce4b252b1015bf4cb3c32">&#9670;&nbsp;</a></span>func()</h2>
```

Clearly the `file_` in the Python version should not be present (the `file_` has nothing to do with the filename as a filename like `something.py` gives the same result).

Note: I found in the code, `memberdef.cpp`:

```
// member is in a namespace, but is written as part of the file documentation
// as well, so we need to make sure its label is unique.
```

Edit: base on the suggestion I already made in the comments I just I've just pushed this as a proposed patch to github (pull request 720, https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/720).

Comment: so what does that comment mean at memberdef. it seems intentionally added. I wonder how we can have like a workaround.. what do you think about instead of using file, to use package instead?

Comment: I think that the added `file_` probably should not be valid for python, but as said before is is something to look at, due to the complexity of the code (all the different programming languages supported) it not so easy. I didn't investigate yet but ,aybe / probably normally the package name is used and here we don't have a package name and a dummy name is used that is not filtered out again.

Comment: sure. Thanks for that albert. I tried the toy examples of package on Doxygen doc site, but did not work (tab never shown), what do you mean with a dummy name maybe I am doing that wrong, or maybe a small example with the MWE provided

Comment: The dummy name might be set inside doxygen (and cannot be influenced from the outside).

Comment: No dummy name but it looks like that the file is setup as a namespace although Python does not know (to the best of my knowledge) about namespaces as in the sense of Cpp (and Fortran: modules). Please prove me wrong when the above saying is not correct. I think that Python should be excluded in memberdef.cpp by adding `&& lang != SrcLangExt_Python` to the `if` statement just above the cite comment in this answer. @DaWNFoRCe is it possible for you to test this and report back so when succesful I can create a proposed patch for it?